# Spring Boot Starter Cassandra - Missing CassandraCustomConversions

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I need to add a custom converter to Cassandra for converting Date to Timestamp. But it seems like Spring Boot Starter Cassandra does not contain this (yet? ) . Is there any other way or am I missing something?

Comment: you can use extra codecs from Java Driver https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/custom_codecs/extras/